# Change button styling after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wanting a button to change it's appearance AFTER it's been clicked on and have it stay that way. I've tried css using "button:focus" and it'll work, but as soon as another button or anything else is clicked any previously selected button will rever back to it's original styling.

I have default styling set and hover styling set but can't get the visited/clicked-on styling to stay. I don't want it to go back till the page is reloaded. Is this something you can't do with css and have to implement with JS?

This is going to be a bit lengthy, but here is what I have so far:

Html:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button id=p1Button><span>Player One, please select me! </span></button>
  <button id=p2Button><span>Player Two, please select me! </span></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button{
  width: 16em;
  color: white;
  background: #0392CF;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-radius: .25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  margin: .5;
  height: 2.2;
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #F37736;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 13em;
}
button:hover span {
  display: none;
}
button:hover:before {
  content:"Clicky Clicky!";
  letter-spacing: .25em;
}
button:focus {
  color: white;
  background: #F37736;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 13em;
}
button:focus span {
  display: none;
}
button:focus:before {
  content:"Clicked!";
  letter-spacing: .25em;
}
```

Comment: You will need JS. Unlike a link, there is no analogue to `:visited` for `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand focus is a stage. Whenever the element loses focus it will change back to old style. And what you want to achieve is triggered by a 'click' event. Using JS is the best way to handle it.

```
document.getElementById('p1Button').addEventListener('click', onClick);
document.getElementById('p2Button').addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick(){
    this.className += ' YourClassHere';
}
```

Also I recommand you using jQuery which should be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this seems to be by using JavaScript. And easier way will be to use jQuery.

In a js file, put the following code to do it with jQuery

```
$("#p1Button").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("yourClassName");
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, then use the code as follows and in HTML, give a reference to that function like `<button onclick="clickedOnButton(this)" id=p1Button><span>Player One, please select me! </span></button>`

```
function clickedOnButton(this)
{
    this.className+='yourClassName';
}
```

Add a class in the css file too

```
.yourClassName
{
   /* Style to use when clicked on button. */
}
```